# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas noches amigos estoy realizando una pagina y he creado un formulario de registro estoy trabajando con el modelo MVC en php pero quiero redireccionar con un `header` y me sale esto:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at

Este es mi código:

```
if(isset($_POST["nombreProducto"])){
    $datos = array(
        "nameProduct"=>$_POST["nombreProducto"],
        "amountProduct"=>$_POST["cantidadProducto"],
        "price"=>$_POST["precioProducto"],
        "productId"=>$_POST["idProducto"],
        "identificador"=>$_SESSION["usuario"]
    );
        
    $respuesta = Shop::shopRegister($datos,"tienda");
    
    if($respuesta == "success"){
        header("location:paginainicio.php");
    }else{
        header("location:registroproductos");
    }
}
```

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradezco ya he intentado varias cosas y no entiendo el error ya que soy algo nuevo en la programación.

Comment: Acá hay [muchas preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent) sobre ese mensaje. Sucede cuando ya se ha enviado html a la salida, o se ha impreso algo, antes de redireccionar.

Comment: gracias voy a revisar al parecer es como que un error bastante común cuando se quiere redireccionar

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones que envían/modifican encabezados HTTP deben invocarse antes de realizar cualquier salida,de lo contrario, la llamada falla.

verifica que no tengaas espacios antes de la etiqueta <?php
y que no exista un echo u otra cosa que escape cosas antes de llamar a header.

Mas referencias aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: gracias amigo por el consejo voy a verificar lo que ocurre es que yo estoy en ese archivo imprimiendo con una variable de $_SESSION un dato que viene de la base de datos sabes si de pronto tiene algo que ver con eso