# ¿ Como corregir advertencia Cannot modify header information?

Tags: php, wordpress, headers

He activado el modo debug en WordPress para buscar errores y me muestra varias advertencias, aunque el sitio funcione correctamente.

El mensaje en todo es el mismo:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /wp-includes/functions.php:7023)in /mi-alojamiento/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6865.

Este mensaje se repite para varios archivos, aunque todos los "Warning" apuntan al mismo archivo: `/wp-includes/functions.php:7023`

```
 $scheme_separator = strpos( $path, '://' );
```

--

```
function wp_is_stream( $path ) {
 $scheme_separator = strpos( $path, '://' );

    if ( false === $scheme_separator ) {
        // $path isn't a stream.
        return false;
    }

    $stream = substr( $path, 0, $scheme_separator );

    return in_array( $stream, stream_get_wrappers(), true );
}
```

Los archivos en los que recibo el error son tres:

- wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1438

```
    function wp_admin_headers()
        {
            $policy = 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin';
        
            
            $policy = apply_filters('admin_referrer_policy', $policy);
        
            header(sprintf('Referrer-Policy: %s', $policy));
        }
```

- wp-includes/functions.php on line 6865

```
    function send_frame_options_header() {
     header( 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN' );
    }
```

- wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 10

```
       header('Content-Type: ' . get_option('html_type') . '; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'));
        if (!defined('WP_ADMIN')) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/admin.php';
        }
```

He revisado otras preguntas con este error, he modificado cada uno de los archivos siguiendo instrucciones de otros errores, sin embargo, sigo recibiendo estos Warning.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

[como solucionar Cannot modify header information – headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249084/como-solucionar-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent)

[Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/528592/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-output-star)

etc, etc...

¿ Como se puede corregir esto ?
Gracias

Comment: Estás haciendo un echo o print o cualquier otra salida (incluyendo la salida estándar cuando se interpreta el PHP y genera el HTML) Y DESPUÉS intentas hacer otro echo, print u otra salida. Ahí te dice que ey, ya envié la salida, no me pidas que cambie la cosa. Revisa

Comment: Gracias, he tratado de comprender los significados. Todo funciona a la perfección pero cuando uno ve estos Warning, personalmente quiero corregirlo, aunque mis conocimientos no me lo permita. De ahí que venga en busca de consejo aquí. Tampoco se donde actúan esas funciones, deberia seguir indagando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas el método [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), estás fijando los headers que va a usar la respuesta del servidor, el mensaje HTTP.
Ahí, entre muchas cosas, puedes fijar el location para redirigir si es un 302, cookies, políticas CORS, etc.

Como podrás imaginar, no tiene sentido hacer eso si *ya enviaste el mensaje de respuesta*. Que es lo que te indiqué en el comentario. Esos llamados a `header()` son un warning y no un error porque **son ignorados** ya que la respuesta se fue mucho antes... te está avisando que ese `Referer-policy` no se está aplicando, que ese `Content-type` tampoco y que el `X-Frame` sí que menos. Puedes ver en tu navegador, dev tools, pestaña Network, y mirar en las peticiones, los encabezados de la respuesta. A ver si coincide con lo que esperas.

Te corresponde revisar cómo y cuándo estás haciendo el include_once de esos recursos.

Comment: Gracias @Afabravo. Yo no he construido ese código, es el que tiene el tema que estoy utilizando. Necesito asimilar tus comentarios y ver si logro entender lo que me dices para tratar de hacer algo esta ocasión y por supuesto, en lo sucesivo. Dejame que busque información partiendo de tu respuesta. Gracias

Comment: @unity-student Dale. La cosa es que desde acá tampoco hay mucho más qué añadir sin más código por revisar.

Comment: Ya, estamos hablando de archivos de 8000 lineas de código. Como digo, dame tiempo para buscar información y si se me ocurre algo te pregunto. Grcaias