# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent error php

Tags: php

Tengo una función para iniciar sesión y cuando los valores introducidos son correctos y llamo a **header("location:Index.php")** y me da el siguiente error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd5/260/20836260/public_html/Index.php:1) in /storage/ssd5/260/20836260/public_html/Modelo/UsuariosModelo.php on line 55 (es donde llamo a header("location:Index.php")

```
public function iniciaSesion(){
    $consulta = "select * from usuarios where email=:email";
    $email = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["email"]));
    $pass = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["pass"]));
    $res = $this->db->prepare($consulta);
    $res->bindParam(":email", $email);
    if($res->execute()){
        if($res->rowCount() > 0){
            $reg = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(password_verify($pass,$reg["password"])){
                $_SESSION["name"] = strval($reg["nombre"]);
                $_SESSION["idUser"] = intval($reg["id_usuario"]);
                $_SESSION["user"] = $email;
                $_SESSION["rol"] = $reg["rol"];
                $_SESSION["provincia"] = $reg["provincia"];
                if(isset($_SESSION["errorInicioSesion"])){
                    unset($_SESSION["errorInicioSesion"]);
                }
                header("location:Index.php");
                exit();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [revisa este link, creo que tu respuesta va por aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/586380/como-corregir-advertencia-cannot-modify-header-information)

Comment: El error solo ocurre cuando previamente se ha enviado algo a la salida. Esta salida puede ser un espacio, salto de linea, error, advertencia, etc. Toca revisar todos los archivos incluidos y buscar donde esta ocurriendo dicha salida. Un error común suele ser dejar un espacio antes de abrir el tag de PHP, ejemplo, ` <?php`

Answer (score 0):

Es más un comentario pero no puedo hacerlo, prueba con la L de location en mayúscula:

```
header('Location: index.php')
```